# ChartJS does not work on Windows 10 - in any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser, chart.js

Strange one this, I have just done a clean install of Windows 10 on my laptop. I have a site that uses ChartJS on several pages, and none of them work. I've tried IE11, Edge, Chrome and Firefox. Nothing!

Yet, on my Windows 7 desktop the charts display perfectly on all browsers.

This is an odd problem, and I can't see why it would be doing this - it doesn't require any third party plugins at all does it?

Comment: Did you check the Console?

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised this is a PHP issue which only seems to be replicated on Win 10